# Execute method in global.asax every few minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, timer, webserver

What is the most effective way to execute a method in the Global.asax file every x number of minutes?  Is there a way to have the ASP.NET server run a background thread that fires a tick event after a certain elapsed period?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could have a timer in the Application_Start of the Global.asax, but this is not very flexible since you need to do a request to the application for the timer to start. There are dangers to doing it this way though, as detailed by Haacked:

- http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

A better way of doing it is to have a web service that acts as an interface to your ASP.NET application and have a windows service that calls your web service on scheduled intervals:

More details here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx

Comment: If you do not have access to your server (say it's hosted by a third party) and cannot install Windows services, then you can fake one using the ASP.NET cache: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

Comment: In my particular case, I am okay with requiring a request to be made for the application to start.  Your web service idea is great though, and definitely a more appropriate answer for generic cases of my question.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChrisSinclair is 100% spot on. You should not be developing, with the mindset that you have full access to company resources or client resources. Everything should be portable and expandable, and hence a ASP.net cached solution is really the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you could use combination of HTTPModule and ASP.NET TIMER to do this

http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/04/06/create-custom-http-module-to-periodically-refresh-cache-or-some-other-work/

(or)

You could use AJAX Timer control .

http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/06/12/refresh-gridview-intervals-using-ajax-timer/

Answer (score -1):

Put a `System.Timers.Timer` object in `Application_Start ()` in `Global.asax`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: You beat me by 22 seconds, but I actually typed something :)

Comment: Not a very good idea. An ASP.Net application may have been shut down (typically the configuration of hosted web servers, where application is shut down after a period of inactivity and only started on receiving a new request).

Comment: @MoizTankiwala is correct. Not a good idea. Most web services have a timeout, which you may not have control over. Web servers may crash. Then what!? You may need to host your ASP.net page on a remote service that at least gives some gaurantees it won't stop - cloud, etc. Try to avoid using server internals to do the job. Use the cache!